# TFS - auto increment number field in a WITT (e.g. Bug's)

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is there a way to auto increment a number field in a WITT (e.g. Bug). We've got a requirement that we want contiguous Bug ids (note - not its actual id but a separate field).

Can this field be done unique per collection OR unique per project (thus duplicates would occur in the collection).

---edit

I've no idea how to tackle this, but I'm wondering if I could use a globalist, e.g. bug creation triggers the adding (replacement) of a value to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer goes into the same direction like aaronbjorks one.

Create a webservice that gets alerted if a new bug is created, then just write down the bug ID in a database with an identity column. On the workitem you can create a custom control, that gets the identity for that bug from the database and displays it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this directly through the WIT platform. You would need to write some sort of custom service to do this for you on the creation of a new bug.

Comment: do you mean something like a SOAP service which I interrogate for a value? or would it be a process running on the TFS host? would it modify the WITT after it was created, how would that be triggered? (and thanks for your input)

Comment: Check this out: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/assafstone/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be exporting your items query to Excel and let it update the IDs upon Publish. Make sure once an ID was assigned, tag it as [FROZEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194953.aspx).